# Alt-F9 is missing in ubuntu's byobu

Tags: byobu, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> toggle send keys to all splits under fedora 22's byobu, but under Ubuntu trusty this combination doesn't even appear in help. Is it possible to enable it? I'm using tmux as back-end, byobu 5.77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [added in byobu 5.87](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kirkland/byobu/trunk/revision/2386), which is newer than Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty)'s version of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).  You could install the latest version of Byobu from ppa:byobu/ppa on Trusty, if you like.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*